# Fixing NameError: NameError: name 'key_p' is not defined?

Tags: python, function, keystroke

I have written the below keystroke system that returns values from `on_press()` function and `on_release()?` function into a dictionary called `key_dict`. Running the script, returns a NameError even though I have defined it globally in both functions.

Any ideas?
Thanks

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from datetime import datetime


def on_press(key):
    global key_p,key_pt,key_r,key_rt
    key_p = key
    key_pt = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    keyall = {'Key_Pressed':key_p, 'Key_Time':key_pt}
    return key_p, key_pt

def on_release(key):
    global key_p,key_pt,key_r,key_rt
    key_r = key
    key_rt = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    keysall = {'Key_Released':key_r, 'Release_Time':key_rt}
    return key_r, key_rt
    if key == Key.enter:
        # Stop listener
        return False

key_dict = {'Key_Pressed':[key_p],
            'Key_Time':[key_pt],
            'Key_Released':[key_r],
            'Release_Time':[key_rt]}

print(key_dict)


# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `global` tells python to use the global variable called `key_p`, it does not initialize it.

You should initialize your global variables in the global scope first. Then use `global` keyword on each function.

---

Edit:

```
key_dict = {'Key_Pressed':[key_p],
            'Key_Time':[key_pt],
            'Key_Released':[key_r],
            'Release_Time':[key_rt]}
```

`key_p` is not defined here because you are in the global scope. `key_p` is initialized inside `on_press` function.

Comment: Hi Carles, thank you for your response. I initialized the variables outside the function and it worked. But it only showed the value I initialized. How do I dynamically replace the initial value with what the users type?
For example; key_p = on_press()

Comment: @aa888817  You should initialize and print `key_dict` inside `on_release`. This way all variables `key_X` will have the correct values.